# Convergence of a bounded sequence

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence

The question is Let ${(a_n)}$ be a sequence with range $\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$. Prove that the series $(a_n10^{-n})$ converges.

Now, since the range is given, we know that is bounded. But is it enough to say it converges?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** First try to decide what this question is *really* about. Maybe do this by assuming that $a_0=3$, $a_1=1$, $a_2=4$, and writing down  the first three partial sums of the corresponding series.

You need to show that the **partial sums** of the **series** are bounded. If you start the summation at $n=1$, it will turn out that $1$ is an upper bound. (If you start at $n=0$, then $10$ is an upper bound.)

The rest will then be easy, for it is obvious that the partial sums are non-decreasing, and therefore we have convergence.